# How to clear the compare list?

Tags: magento-1.7, compare

I need that, when the user goes to the compare list page it will reset so if he navigates to the products again he will have to choose different products for the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the code that Magento uses in the `clearAction()` of the product compare controller and addapt it a little:

```
$items = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection');
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $items->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());
    } elseif ($this->_customerId) {
        $items->setCustomerId($this->_customerId);
    } else {
        $items->setVisitorId(Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId());
    }

/** @var $session Mage_Catalog_Model_Session */
$session = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session');

try {
    $items->clear();
    Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate(); 
}
catch (Exception $e){
    //do nothing
}
```

You can add this code at the end of your compare list template (.phtml) but a clean option would be to either override the list block (`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List`) and add this code in the `_afterToHtml()` methods, or create an observer for the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` and check if the block passed to the observer matches your block (`instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List`) then execute the code above.

I recommend overriding the block and adding the code in the `_afterToHtml()` method because the event is called for each rendered block and it may add an overhead to page rendering.

Comment: That class doesn't have _afterToHtml() method, should I simply add it?

Comment: Simply add it. The list block is a child of the class `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` that has the method and the method is called inside `toHtml()`

Comment: I'm getting a blank page :S Edit: I get a blank page if I add the method to the class, it works adding it on the phtml

Comment: You should end your `_afterToHtml($html)` method with `return parent::_afterToHtml($html)`. But if it works the 'quick & dirty' way, when adding it to the phtml file and you don't plan to pack your code as a commercial extension then I guess there is no problem with that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll leave it like that, thank you very much!